# Visual Studio 2019 "Solution Explorer" "View Code" icon C#

Tags: visual-studio, solution-explorer

Does anyone else have this issue? There does not seem to be a way to edit the Solution Explorer toolbar. One of the icons for Solution Explorer is missing in my C# projects.
I am using Version 16.10.3.

[image: Visual Studio 2019]

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Folks, I figured out the issue.  When you create a .NET Core 5.0 project the VS environment is setup different. I deleted the .NET 5.0 project and recreated as a .NET Standard one with the same name and the icon showed up again.

In fact, the Studio 'solution' version is different although your using the exact same VS application.  Problem solved for now.

Comment: The VSTeam has the issue 'Under Investigation'.  It seems to be an issue with the (.NET Core 3.1 & .NET 5.0) environment.  

REF:
https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Solution-Explorer:-View-Code-F7-missin/899716

Answer (score 1):

I managed to add this icon to the wrong place, but maybe you can find the right place and update this answer.

[image]

I did this by [customizing menus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-customize-menus-and-toolbars-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019):

1. Clicking **Tools | Customize...**
2. Selecting **Commands** tab
3. Clicking **Add Command...**
4. Selecting **View**
5. Selecting **View Code**, and then **OK**

[image]

It looks like what you have to do is find the right place to add it in the first place.

The options under **Commands** are **Menu bar**, **Toolbar**, and **Context menu**, none of which seems to fit. I looked around briefly; maybe you can do a more in depth search to find the right spot.

I have several extensions installed. One of these modifies the Solution Explorer behavior for dynamic nodes. It's possible that extension or another is interfering with this icon. Try also disabling your extensions and see if that has an effect.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful. For now I just added to the end of my menu bar.  It's really weird though because it shows up for some projects and not for others.  Which seems to suggest that its a bug and/or a VS configuration issue.  

I created a question for the VS Team.  However, wondering if anyone else experienced the same issue.  Thanks again.